# Rails redirect_to with anchor failing to scroll

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, anchor

After my controller action does what it needs to, I want to redirect_to a url with its corresponding anchor. My redirect is working, and the URL shows it, but it's not scrolling down like it's supposed to.

```html
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to my_wagers_path(:anchor => "wagerNotif"), notice: result_message }
end
```

None of the many existing solutions I tried seem to work. I am using turbolinks. Any insight appreciated.

Comment: Does to page contain an element with an existing id?

Comment: @max yes, it does. I can manually get to it by typing #wagerNotif into the url bar, 80% of the time. The other 20% it will reload the page if I type it like that